# How does ASP.NET raise events on the client?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

For example, when a user clicks a `<button>`, I know  the event handler on server side will execute.
But how event raised on client side? As the initial page (using `GET`) is purely [html](/questions/tagged/html) on client side, is the event raised by [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)?

If yes, does it mean *.aspx* will automatically generate [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) code on client side first?

For example, I have a [asp](/questions/tagged/asp) button on an *.aspx* page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate" Width="122px" OnClick="btnCalculate_Click" />
```

`OnClick` indicates that this is an [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) event, but where do I find the applicable [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) code?

Comment: It depends, could you post a code with some example? It will help to answer your question.

Comment: What kind of button are we talking about? Is it a `<form>` submit button?
Then there's a post or get request (specified by the form tag), is it a `<button>` tag? Then there's most likely Javascript involved. The answer to your head line is: ASP.NET does not raise any events on the client, your browser does by parsing the client side "code" (html, javascript, ...).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479302.aspx

Comment: @RicardoPontual I have edit my post to include an example

Answer (score 5):

`<asp:{Control>}>` are all server sided controls, the onclick event you're seeing is not the correct [html](/questions/tagged/html) representation.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate" Width="122px" OnClick="btnCalculate_Click" />
```

Will result in something remotely like this:

```
<input id="btnCalculate" type="submit" value="Calculate"/>
```

which refers to a callback (post/get request) on the server which then calls `btnCalculate_Click()` defined in your View's [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code (.aspx.cs):

```
public void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   ...
}
```

In comparison this [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) ASPX code would directly convert to the same [html](/questions/tagged/html) "code":

```
<button id="btnCalculate" onClick="btnCalculate_Click()"/>
```

So it would instead tell the client (browser engine) to look for an applicable [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) function (e.g. in your `site.js` or any other provided [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) resource):

```
function btnCalculate_Click(){
    alert("This is client side scripting");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to revise the `Client-Server-Paradigm`.

A client makes a request, the server then accepts this request.
As a result, the server sends an "answer" (response) to the client, which is then received by it.

Comment: I know that, but I don't know where is the OnClick (javascript) from, is it generated by original button control on aspx?

Comment: Yes, the on click event is a request that start from the client and get response from server